# Getting exception while include ngroute in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am getting error while using `ngRoute` in angular.js.

Error:

> angular.js:6Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=ReferenceE…20%20at%20ge%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fangularjs%2Fangular.js%3A19%3A484)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:6(anonymous function) @ angular.js:40r @ angular.js:7g @ angular.js:39db @ angular.js:43c @ angular.js:20Bc @ angular.js:21ge @ angular.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular.js:316b @ angular.js:189Sf @ angular.js:37d @ angular.js:36

I am providing my code below:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#form"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>Open form </a></li>
 </ul>
```

config.js:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/form', {
                templateUrl : 'form.html',
                controller  : 'formController'
            });
        otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
})

app.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see This is home page!';
    });
    app.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.address = 'Contact us! Rasulgarh,Bhubaneswar';
    });
    app.controller('formController',function($scope){
    })
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Angularjs</title>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="angularroute.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
</head>

<body>
<header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing and form Example</a>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#form"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i>Open form </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
<div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here when I am clicking on 'home' link nothing is happening and the above error is coming in console. I am using `1.5.7` for both angular.js and angular-route.

Comment: where you include the angular-route.js ?

Comment: @Mostafa: Check my updated post.

Comment: Something is wrong here: `}); otherwise({ redirectTo: '/` });` - That's an invalid object that causing a syntax error

Comment: Oh, this is 4 years ago! lol